# Google play developer account payment not working

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console, google-console-developer

I'm trying to create a google play developer account, but at the first step of the payment, it won't work.
[image: First step]

I already added my credit card to my Google account : 
[image: Credit card]

But when I click on **Continue to payment** button, I don't see anything, when I checked my console, this is what I see : 
[image]

I've also logged in only with a single google account, I've signout from all other accounts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question and not a programming question. Contact Google Play customer service for help with their site or your specific account. We cannot assist with those issues. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576) for more information.

Comment: You have to use the international card for that somekind of platinum chip will be installed on those card. I have used SBI Global VISA card it worked note SBI VISA is different then SBI GLOBAL VISA so make sure your card is international

Comment: hi, did your issue got resolved?

Comment: Looks like I got the same issue, have you resolved it?

Comment: Have you googled for error 668269003 ? I have this at the moment, and articles I found suggested it might fix itself in an hour or two?

Comment: For those who having the same problem, just try using VPS to another location, don't know what's going on with google but using VPS worked for me.

Comment: The issue was with google in my country (Morocco), so use a VPN or ask someone who lives in another country like I did (French)